Pandas split revenue according to threshold table
I have two dataframes, sales table & threshold table. Party A has to split revenue with Party B if the sales reach a certain threshold in either USD/AUD. This split is set by the threshold below, and can be changed anytime. For example, below shows a threshold change effective on 12 Dec 2025.



Effective date
revenue threshold (USD)
revenue threshold (AUD)
Party A Split%
Party B Split%




1-1-2024
100

50%
50%


1-1-2024
200

80%
20%


12-12-2025
100
150
50%
50%


12-12-2025

300
70%
30%


12-12-2025
300
450
90%
10%



On sales table below, how can I get the resulting calculated columns "Party A Split US$" and "Party B Split US$" in Python? (btw, each sales are recorded in both USD & AUD using that day's FX rate. Rmb, threshold applies if either currency hits it.)



Sales_date
Invoice#
revenue (USD)
revenue (AUD)
Party A Split US$
Party B Split US$




6-6-2024
001
$10
$15
$10 (No split to B, no threshold met)
0


6-6-2024
002
$100
$149
$50 (50%)
$50 (50%)


6-6-2024
003
$400
$599
$320 (80%)
$80 (20%)


12-30-2025
004
$99
$149
$99 (No split to B, no threshold met)
0


12-30-2025
005
$200
$301
$140(70%)
$60 (30%)


12-30-2025
006
$301
$440
$270.9 (90%)
$30.1 (10%)



data = {
    "Sales_date": [
        "10-Oct-24",
        "10-Oct-24",
        "10-Oct-24",
        "10-Oct-24",
        "1-Jan-25",
        "1-Jan-25",
        "1-Jan-25",
    ],
    "invoice_num": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    "seller_group": ["RM", "RM", "PBM", "PBM", "PBM", "PBM", "FP"],
    "rev_usd": [100, 200, 10000, 19000, 50, 101, 111],
    "rev_aud": [78000, 10000, 75000, 99000, 50, 60, 333],
}

sales_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

data1 = {
    "Effective date": [
        "1-Oct-24",
        "1-Oct-24",
        "1-Oct-24",
        "1-Oct-24",
        "1-Oct-24",
        "1-Oct-24",
        "1-Jan-25",
        "1-Jan-25",
    ],
    "seller_group": ["RM", "RM", "PBM", "PBM", "PBM", "FP", "PBM", "PBM"],
    "rev threshold (USD)": [0, None, 0, 10000, 20000, 0, 0, 100],
    "rev threshold (AUD)": [0, 100000, 0, 78000, 90000, 0, 0, None],
    "Party A Split%": [0.50, 0.60, 1.00, 1.00, 0.10, 1.00, 1.00, 0.80],
    "Party B Split%": [0.50, 0.40, 0.00, 1.00, 0.90, 0.00, 0.00, 0.20],
}

threshold_df = pd.DataFrame(data1)


Can you please provide the sales and threshold tables in pandas for a minimal reproduceable example?

added into question @dydev

Thanks. However, the examples don't match. Can you please add the expected output?

I would just write a mapping function that processes each row of the sales table and each time consults the threshold table to figure out the split percentage.
Like so
def get_splits(sales_date, revenue_usd, revenue_aud) -> dict[str, float]:
    # Find the latest applicable threshold
    applicable_thresholds = threshold_df[threshold_df['Effective date'] <= sales_date].sort_values(by='Effective date', ascending=False)
    if applicable_thresholds.empty:
        # early return if there are no applicable threshold
        return {'Party A Split%': 100, 'Party B Split%': 0}

    latest_threshold = applicable_thresholds.iloc[0]
    usd_threshold = latest_threshold['revenue threshold (USD)']
    aud_threshold = latest_threshold['revenue threshold (AUD)']

    if (pd.notna(usd_threshold) and revenue_usd >= usd_threshold) or (pd.notna(aud_threshold) and revenue_aud >= aud_threshold):
        return {
            'Party A Split%': latest_threshold['Party A Split%'],
            'Party B Split%': latest_threshold['Party B Split%']
        }
    return {'Party A Split%': 100, 'Party B Split%': 0}

def calculate_splits(row):
    splits = get_splits(row['Sales_date'], row['revenue (USD)'], row['revenue (AUD)'])
    party_a_split_usd = row['revenue (USD)'] * splits['Party A Split%'] / 100
    party_b_split_usd = row['revenue (USD)'] * splits['Party B Split%'] / 100
    return pd.Series([party_a_split_usd, party_b_split_usd], index=['Party A Split US$', 'Party B Split US$'])

sales_df[['Party A Split US$', 'Party B Split US$']] = sales_df.apply(calculate_splits, axis=1)

I'm assuming your threshold table isn't going to get large because it seems to represent some kind of policy that is manually changed from time to time.
If on the other hand the threshold table can indeed get very large, I would consider other ways of making this more efficient like using appropriate indices on the Effective date column and partitioning the table if you're using distributed batch processing.
